# Scheme core language specification

Tags: syntax, lisp, scheme, language-design

I am learning my way around Scheme, and I am especially interested in how the language is constructed. I'm trying to find a nice description of the core syntax for a Scheme implementation. I don't know enough about the standards, but I assume that they all contain macro systems. If not, I'd like to read about a standard that also includes macros (they can't possibly be implemented in simpler Scheme constructs, can they?).

Does anyone have a good reference for the minimal syntax needed for a Scheme dialect?

Just an update:

I also stumbled upon this: http://matt.might.net/articles/compiling-to-java/#sec1. If you also add `define-syntax` and `delay` then it seems like it might be a good start.

In the R5RS specification, the following page appears to be what I was looking for: [formal syntax](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_7.1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it may be a bit dry, you should read over the [R<sup>5</sup>RS spec](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML) or the [R<sup>6</sup>RS spec](http://www.r6rs.org/).

The docs really do not take that long to read through and you can just skim most of the sections until you need more detail. But either document does cover all of the minimal syntax required, including macros.

Comment: R5RS is famously short (~50 pp.). R6RS is a much larger language.

Comment: twopoint718: Yes, that's a known flaw of R5RS.  Regardless, for this question both would be the same, and R6 is likely to be better.

Comment: (Um, *could* be better in fixing small problems in the R5 description.)